# Enable / disable Azure Traffic Manager endpoints

Tags: .net, powershell, azure

Is there a way to disable temporarily a specific endpoint in Azure traffic manager using either REST Api or a Powershell cmdlet?

Or is there a different way to disable an endpoint while the endpoint is maintained without using the Azure portal?

Comment: Can you please describe what do you mean by disabling an endpoint temporarily?

Comment: Guess you could just remove the endpoint and add it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now do this using PowerShell cmdlets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690250.aspx

The sequence would be:

```
Get-AzureTrafficManagerProfile <profileName>
| Set-AzureTrafficManagerEndpoint -DomainName <endpointDomain> -Status Disabled
| Set-AzureTrafficManagerProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Create Definition API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh758257.aspx and set the `<Status>` element to Disabled for the endpoint you are disabling.  When you are ready to re-enable it, just call Create Definition API again with `<Status>` set to Enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure-out how to enable or disable a traffic manager's endpoints using C# with this code sample in GitHub:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/traffic-manager-dotnet-manage-profiles